# Saving dynamically generated Xamarin controls

Tags: c#, xamarin, serialization, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin application where the user cann add and move controlelements like label, button,... around. All these controls are added to an AbsoluteLayout. In the application the user should be able to switch between different layouts. To load the layout i want to use the `LoadFromXaml()` function. .Net Framework has a `XamlWriter()` but my application only has .Net standard. My problem is, how can i save the controls, that the user added to the AbsoluteLayout to a File?

Comment: There is no in-built Forms'-based XAML serializer|save|export, just the LoadFromXaml extension. Personally I would serialize just the view structure using a custom model (it ends up being very light weight over trying to perform a deep serialization of a layout and its contents)